# How can I transform a StringList to one String

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, string, qgis-expression

I have a column in Qgis with type:"StringList" eg
`{ "name": "William", "height": "1.87", "age": 90 }, { "name": "Mary", "height": "1.70", "age":30 }`

When I want to do any kind of transformation (eg: replace "William" with "Mario") I only get the first object in the list in all the columns no matter the number of objects.

Ideally I would like to have this column as "String" but I cannot find any way to transform it to a single String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace texts inside a list, you will need to loop throw that list.

```
array_foreach(
    array:="field-name", -- set inside double quotes the StringList field name
    expression:=replace(@element, 'William', 'Mario')
)
```

and if you want to convert a StringList into string calculate a new field of type String and use [array_to_string()](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#array-to-string) or create a JSON string with [to_json()](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-json)